# How can I trigger livereload on changes to HTML files in webpack without having webpack process those files at all?

Tags: javascript, webpack, livereload

In other words: I want webpack to *only* watch for changes to `.html` files and trigger the livereload plugin on change, but to do nothing else with those files.

As it is, I'm receiving the following error when I run my webpack watcher:

```
ERROR in chunk signup [entry]
index.js
Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename index.js (chunks index and signup)
```

I have 2 files in the `./templates` directory: `index.html` and `signup.html`.

This is my current webpack config: https://gist.github.com/johnthedebs/c2b3f23ffde2511217926b862bc34b1b

And these are the package versions I'm currently using:

```
    "webpack": "4.37.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.6",
    "webpack-glob-entries-plugin": "0.3.2",
    "webpack-livereload-plugin": "2.2.0"
```

Let me know if there is any other info I can provide that would be helpful :). Thanks!